# Firebase Bulk Update / Delete

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm building a chat app using Swift and Firebase 3 and I'm wondering how one would handle multiple message deletes / updates. For example, if one user decides to delete a conversation, I would like to delete / update a flag on all the messages in that conversation.

Is there a way to do this with Swift and Firebase 3? Maybe using a REST request? 
I was unable to find something related to this in their documentation.

If this is not yet supported in Firebase, is it a good approach to flag the last message and then download the messages in reverse order (starting from the newest), and just stop at the flagged message?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a look at [this blogpost](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/09/introducing-multi-location-updates-and_86.html). is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Yes. Thank you! 
This works for updating, any idea on how to delete multiple children?

Comment: you can delete children by setting their value to null.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can easily do it with "updateChildValues", picking a ref that's a common ancestor all the way to root if needed.

Here's an example:

```
     [super.ref updateChildValues:@{
                       [NSString stringWithFormat:@"followers/%@/%@", _user.userID,
                        [FPAppState sharedInstance].currentUser.userID]: lastPostID,
                       [NSString stringWithFormat:@"people/%@/following/%@",
                        [FPAppState sharedInstance].currentUser.userID, _user.userID]: @YES
                       }];
```

https://github.com/firebase/friendlypix/blob/master/ios/FriendlyPix/FPAccountViewController.m#L114

Comment: Thank you! This works for updating.
Do you have any idea on how to delete multiple children?

Comment: You can set their values to [NSNull null]